# nodeJS .exports, require question about the object that is going to be returned

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let’s say we have f1 and f2 and we export an object of properties/methods to f2. When I run the f2 file the console displays both the f1 and f2 outputs.

f1

```
var counter = function(arr){
    console.log(arr.length);
};

let arr1=['0','2','3','4','1'];


let counter2 = function(arr){
    console.log(arr.length*2);
}

counter2(arr1);



module.exports = {
    counter,
    arr1
};
```

f2

```
let  count=require('./t1');




count.counter(['1']);
```

When I run the f2 file at the console in the end they seem to appear both 10 and 1 in that exact order even though I never exported counter 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly **call** `counter2` inside f1:

> ```
> counter2(arr1);
> ```

Code in a required module is evaluated. If it wasn't, it wouldn't run the `module.exports =` line and nothing would be exported.

Since you call the function (as well are defining it), it is called.

Answer (score 1):

you called `counter2` inside f1, and since you imported f1 it's mean you will execute the whole code inside this file, which means you will execute the calling of `counter2`